# Why do I need to choose my processor architecture when downloading an application for Linux?

Tags: linux, operating-system, hardware

Isn't the operating system an abstraction on top of the hardware?

Making hardware architectures irrelevant for software being run on the same operating system?

If so why do I need to choose my processor architecture (e.g: ARM or amd64) when downloading NodeJS for example?

Comment: It abstracts some hardware.  It doesn't abstract away the CPU for applications that include assembly code or that use CPU-specific features like hypervisors.  Ever try using Nvidia video card drivers  for an AMD or intel card?  It won't work, despite the drivers running on an OS.

Answer (score 3):

Different platforms abstract away different things:

- Java/WASM abstract away CPU architecture, memory model, device access, terminal output and file access.

  - Any program can run anywhere.
- Linux/Windows abstract away device access, terminal output and file access.

  - Any program built for that CPU and ABI can run.
- DOS abstracts away terminal output and file access.

  - Any program built for that CPU and ABI that includes drivers for devices can run.
- BIOS abstracts away terminal output.

  - Any program built for that CPU and ABI that includes device drivers and file system drivers to load its own data can run.

You need to account for everything that is not abstracted away, and on Linux that includes the CPU architecture.

It's better than DOS where you additionally needed to make sure your program supported your sound card, but not as convenient as Java where a single Android app can run on both x86 and arm64.

Comment: What is terminal output, file access and device access?

Comment: Writing text to screen, reading/writing files on hard drives, and accessing peripheral devices like mice, joysticks, printers, sound cards, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably heard programs can be compiled to "machine code." These are low-level instructions for the hardware, different for every type of machine (and are influenced not only by CPUs but also by peripherals).

The NodeJS interpreter is written in C and C++ and compiled to machine code. This compiled code is only valid on a particular type of a machine. So you need to download the correct version of the NodeJS interpreter for your machine.

You can write pure JS code to be run on NodeJS and then it will usually not depend on the machine type - it will be "universal" to an extent. But as soon as the JS code (this is usually true for some specific modules and libraries) uses native code (C, C++, & others) for performance reasons, this code gets to be compiled for a specific machine, and then the JS module also becomes bound to a specific machine.

The operating system has little to no influence in all of this. It basically says how the machine code will be written into a file (e.g. which file format to use), and abstracts access to hardware (such as the disk drives) in a way this code can use.

Historically, there have been attempts to create operating systems which would completely abstract the underlying machine in a way which makes programs completely portable. They usually do it by disallowing user-written machine code (i.e. user-compiled programs) to execute, and only allow interpreted code to run.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system installed must support the processor(s), data buses and  memory addressing of the hardware.

At a systems level, in kernel code and device drivers it is impossible to ignore details of the hardware architecture. Applications typically sit a level above all this but are still dependent on the abstraction layers below.

Incidentally, Node.js is written in part in C and C++ which takes advantage of the performance improvements offered by 64 bit processing. Wrangling an optimised performance has been a key objective of node.js design, it has been refactored more than once to that end.